# Selecting url from the href attribute with Kimonolabs

Tags: css, web-scraping

I am using Kimonolabs to retrieve data from from a ecommerce site: http://www.apartments-split.com/

I can't get the url of the button "get detail", Kimonolabs takes the url of the image, not the link.

I am not a pro on CSS, but how can I select the a href and not the src in the advanced mode?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you provide the code you're trying to use to retrieve the 'href' attribute?

Comment: I am just using the default Kimono set up which is: td > div > span > a > img but this brings back the image of the button "Details" when I'd like the url of the target page. I may have to select the right one with CSS and did some tests, but could not get it

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the CSS nested path to the required attribute.  I have had some issues extracting specific data using KimonoLabs but I think that is a limitation in the CSS file structure of the website being scraped.

To answer your question I believe "td > div > span > a" may work.
By using "td > div > span > a > img" you are specifically choosing data assciated with the "img" attribute, and not the "a" (or link) attribute.